# Assigning Rcpp objects into an Rcpp List yields duplicates of the last element

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am trying to take a `Rcpp::CharacterMatrix` and convert each row to its own element within an `Rcpp::List`.

However, the function that I have written to do so has an odd behavior where every entry of the list corresponds to the last row of matrix. Why is it so? Is this some pointer related concept? Please explain.

**Function:**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List char_expand_list(CharacterMatrix A) {
  CharacterVector B(A.ncol());

  List output;

  for(int i=0;i<A.nrow();i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<A.ncol();j++) {
      B[j] = A(i,j);
    }

    output.push_back(B);
  }

  return output;
}
```

**Test Matrix:**

This is the matrix `A` that is passed to the above function.

```
mat = structure(c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "a"  "a" 
# [2,] "b"  "b"  "b" 
# [3,] "c"  "c"  "c"
```

**Output:**

Above function should take this matrix as input and return a list of rows of matrix like so:

```
char_expand_list(mat)
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "a" "a"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "b" "b" "b"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c"
```

But instead I am getting something different:

```
char_expand_list(mat)
# [[1]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c"
```

As can be seen, the output has the last element, e.g. the matrix row of "c", repeated for the first and second list elements. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happening here is largely the result of how Rcpp objects work. 
In particular, `CharacterVector` acts as a pointer to a memory location.
By defining this memory location outside the `for` loop, the result is
a "global" pointer. That is, when an update to `B` occurs in the loop
this subsequently updates all variants of `B` that have been conveniently stored in the `Rcpp::List`. Hence, the repeated lines of `"c"` throughout 
the list.

With this being said, it is a very, very, very **bad** idea to use `.push_back()` on any `Rcpp` data types as you will end up copying to and fro the ever expanding object. Copying will occur as Rcpp data types hide the underlying `SEXP` that controls the R object, which must be recreated. As a result, you should try one of the following approaches:

- Rearrange where the `Rcpp::CharacterVector` is created to be inside the first `for` loop and preallocate `Rcpp::List` space.
- Switch to using only C++ standard library objects and convert at the end to the appropriate type.

  - `std::list` with `std::vector<T>` type `T` (i.e. `std::string`)
  - `Rcpp::wrap(x)` to return the correct object or modify the function return type from `Rcpp::List` to `std::list<std::vector<T> >`.
- Preallocate `Rcpp::List` space and use `std::vector<T>` type `T` (i.e. `std::string`).
- Preallocate `Rcpp::List` space and make a `clone()` of the Rcpp object before storing it in the list.

---

#### Option 1

Here we rearrange the function by moving the declaration for `B` into the
first loop, preallocate the list space, and access the output list normally.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List char_expand_list_rearrange(Rcpp::CharacterMatrix A) {
  Rcpp::List output(A.nrow());

  for(int i = 0; i < A.nrow(); i++) {
    Rcpp::CharacterVector B(A.ncol());

    for(int j = 0; j < A.ncol(); j++) {
      B[j] = A(i, j);
    }

    output[i] = B;
  }

  return output;
}
```

#### Option 2

Here we removed `Rcpp::CharacterVector` in favor of `std::vector<std::string>` and substituted `Rcpp::List` for `std::list<std::vector<std::string> >`. At the end, we convert the standard object to an `Rcpp::List` via `Rcpp::wrap()`.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List char_expand_std_to_list(Rcpp::CharacterMatrix A) {
  std::vector<std::string> B(A.ncol());

  std::list<std::vector<std::string> > o;

  for(int i = 0 ;i < A.nrow(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < A.ncol(); j++) {
      B[j] = A(i, j);
    }

    o.push_back(B);
  }

  return Rcpp::wrap(o);
}
```

Giving:

```
mat = structure(c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
char_expand_std_to_list(mat)
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "a" "a"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "b" "b" "b"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c"
```

#### Option 3

Alternatively, you could aim to keep the `Rcpp::List`, but just declare the size
it is expecting ahead of time and still use a `std::vector<T>` element.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List char_expand_list_vec(Rcpp::CharacterMatrix A) {
  std::vector<std::string> B(A.ncol());

  Rcpp::List o(A.nrow());

  for(int i = 0; i < A.nrow(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < A.ncol(); j++) {
      B[j] = A(i, j);
    }

    o[i] = B;
  }

  return o;
}
```

#### Option 4

Lastly, with space predefined for a list, there is an explicit clone of the 
data at each iteration.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List char_expand_list_clone(Rcpp::CharacterMatrix A) {
  Rcpp::CharacterVector B(A.ncol());
  Rcpp::List output(A.nrow());

  for(int i = 0; i < A.nrow(); i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < A.ncol(); j++) {
      B[j] = A(i, j);
    }

    output[i] = clone(B);
  }

  return output;
}
```

#### Benchmark

The benchmark results show that **Option 1** with a rearrangement and preallocation
of space performs the best. The runner-up second is **Option 4**, which
involves cloning each vector before saving it into the `Rcpp::List`.

```
library("microbenchmark")
library("ggplot2")

mat = structure(c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))

micro_mat_to_list = 
  microbenchmark(char_expand_list_rearrange(mat),
                 char_expand_std_to_list(mat),
                 char_expand_list_vec(mat),
                 char_expand_list_clone(mat))
micro_mat_to_list
# Unit: microseconds
#                             expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
#  char_expand_list_rearrange(mat) 1.501 1.9255 3.22054 2.1965 4.8445  6.797   100
#     char_expand_std_to_list(mat) 2.869 3.2035 4.90108 3.7740 6.4415 27.627   100
#        char_expand_list_vec(mat) 1.948 2.2335 3.83939 2.7130 5.2585 24.814   100
#      char_expand_list_clone(mat) 1.562 1.9225 3.60184 2.2370 4.8435 33.965   100
```

[image: Benchmark plot]