# How to correctly change a list of a ListMatrix in rcpp in R

Tags: r, indexing, rcpp

I would like to change the elements of a list of a ListMatrix in rcpp, but always failed to do that. Please see the the following toy example:

```
library("Rcpp")
cppFunction('
ListMatrix ListMatrixType(ListMatrix x){
            NumericMatrix a = x(0,0);
            a(0,0) = 100;
            return x;
            }
            ')
x = matrix(list(matrix(0,3,2)),2,2)
a = ListMatrixType(x)
a[[1,1]]
a[[2,2]]
```

I expect only `a[[1,1]` is changed, but why the `a[[2,2]]` is also changed?

```
> a[[1,1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  100    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0
> a[[2,2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  100    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0
```

I must misunderstand the indexing rule in rcpp. So my question is how to correctly change the elements of each list? I suppose each list contains a matrix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Welcome to shared environments and Rcpp's use of pointers.

There are two ways to address *R*'s treatment of objects in a shared environment to avoid the domino update associated with the function.

1. perform a deep copy of the object and then update the matrix list position or
2. have only unique elements inside the list (e.g. no duplicated matrices)

---

To begin, let's look at the memory allocation for this *shared* memory list. For convenience -- and to avoid `tracemem()` -- we'll use the `lobstr` package to explore the shared environment. The package is currently GitHub-only and can be obtained using:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("r-lib/lobstr")
```

With `lobstr` in hand, let's take a look at the underlying memory addresses of the matrix list in *R*...

```
x = matrix(list(matrix(0,3,2)),2,2)
lobstr::obj_addrs(x)
# [1] "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8"
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
# identical memory addresses for all objects
```

Notice that all objects share the *same* memory location. Thus, *R* is treating each of these elements inside the list as being the same. *R* opts for this behavior to reduce the size of data in memory as each element belongs to the same *shared environment*.

This is particularly problematic for *Rcpp* as it is manipulating **pointers**, e.g. a location in memory that shows where a *value* is stored, and *not* **values**, e.g. a variable that holds a value like an `int` or a `double`.

Due to this **pointer** behavior, two actions occur:

1. all of the matrices in the matrix list are updated simultaneously, and
2. the overall object `x` is updated without requiring a return statement.

If we modify your function slightly, the second point is more apparent.

#### Modified Function to Illustrate Pointers

**Note:** This function no longer has a return type, yet we are still seeing the `x` object change in *R*'s environment.

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void ListMatrixType_pointer(Rcpp::ListMatrix x){
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix a = x(0, 0);
  a(0, 0) = 100;
}
```

#### Output

```
ListMatrixType_pointer(x)
str(x)
# List of 4
# $ : num [1:3, 1:2] 100 0 0 0 0 0
# $ : num [1:3, 1:2] 100 0 0 0 0 0
# $ : num [1:3, 1:2] 100 0 0 0 0 0
# $ : num [1:3, 1:2] 100 0 0 0 0 0
# - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2
```

Notice, we do *not* have to **return** a value as `x` is automatically updated. Furthermore, we still have the *same* memory location for each of the elements, e.g.

```
lobstr::obj_addrs(x)
# [1] "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8"
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
# identical memory addresses for all objects
```

### Deep Copies of Matrix

To get around the identical memory addresses, you can deeply clone the object and then save it back into the `ListMatrix`. The `clone()` function instantiates a new block of memory to store the values to. Thus, modifying one element no longer will trigger a domino update. Furthermore, when you add a cloned object back to a list, the memory address changes for only that element.

#### Using `clone()` to make a deep copy

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void ListMatrixType_clone(Rcpp::ListMatrix x){
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix a = x(0, 0);

  // Perform a deep copy of a into b
  // and, thus, changing the memory address
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix b = Rcpp::clone(a);
  b(0, 0) = 100;

  // Update x with b
  x(0, 0) = b;
}
```

Output

```
ListMatrixType_clone(x)
str(x)
# List of 4
# $ : num [1:3, 1:2] 100 0 0 0 0 0
# $ : num [1:3, 1:2] 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ : num [1:3, 1:2] 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ : num [1:3, 1:2] 0 0 0 0 0 0
# - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2

lobstr::obj_addrs(x)
# [1] "0x7fceb811a7e8" "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8"
#             ^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^ 
#            different memory addresses
```

### Unique Elements in a List

To emphasize the need for unique elements, consider modifying the matrix in the first position of the matrix list, the memory address for *only the first element* will **change**; the rest of the addresses will remain the same. e.g.

```
x[[1, 1]] = matrix(1, 2, 2)
lobstr::obj_addrs(x)
# [1] "0x7fceb811a7e8" "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8" "0x7fceb69757c8"
#             ^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^ 
#            different memory addresses
```

### Additional Resources

For further reading on this topic please see any of the linked posts below that emphasize pointer behavior associated with *Rcpp* (**Disclaimer:** I wrote them):

- [Assigning Rcpp objects into an Rcpp List yields duplicates of the last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502121/assigning-rcpp-objects-into-an-rcpp-list-yields-duplicates-of-the-last-element/37516536#37516536)
- [Declare a variable as a reference in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363076/declare-a-variable-as-a-reference-in-rcpp/48363220#48363220)
- [Deciding between NumericVector and arma::vec in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170166/deciding-between-numericvector-and-armavec-in-rcpp/50181097#50181097)
- [Should I prefer Rcpp::NumericVector over std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602024/should-i-prefer-rcppnumericvector-over-stdvector/41602289#41602289)

#### Miscellaneous note on Object Sizes

Note: `object.size()` from `utils` in Base R provides an incorrect calculation of the shared environment sizes. c.f. [`?utils::object.size`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/object.size.html)

> This function merely provides a rough indication: it should be reasonably accurate for atomic vectors, but does not detect if elements of a list are shared, for example. (Sharing amongst elements of a character vector is taken into account, but not that between character vectors in a single object.)

```
lobstr::obj_size(x)
# 424 B
utils::object.size(x)
# 1304 bytes
```

So, due to the shared environment, the object size of the list is about 1/3.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and heuristic explanation! Great to know that R's implicit behavior and how to overcome this problem in Rcpp:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you misunderstand the indexing in Rcpp.

Not only `a[[1,1]]` and `a[[2,2]]` were changed, I believe `a[[1,2]]` and `a[[2,1]]` were also changed.

If we use another way to generate the matrix `x`

```
x = matrix(data = c(list(matrix(0,3,2)),
                    list(matrix(0,3,2)),
                    list(matrix(0,3,2)),
                    list(matrix(0,3,2))), 2, 2)
```

We will see `a[[2,2]]` hasn't been changed.

```
> x = matrix(data = c(list(matrix(0,3,2)),
+                     list(matrix(0,3,2)),
+                     list(matrix(0,3,2)),
+                     list(matrix(0,3,2))), 2, 2)
> a = ListMatrixType(x)
> a[[1,1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  100    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0
> a[[2,2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I believe @coatless's explanation also includes your answer as an approach to overcoming my problem.